# How to get project name as a variable in intellij to use for XML files?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, ant

Simple problem:

I wanna build my project and have it automatically be named after my project-directory.
Any clean way on how I can get my project name as a variable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As described in docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html

in IntelliJ IDEA, there are some pre-defined variables.

It seems you could work around this one

`$PROJECT_DIR$` - stands for the directory where your project is stored.

Comment: thanks for your answer!                                                                                             
<property name="jar.name" value="$PROJECT_DIR$"/>                                                                              if i try to do this, my jar is simply named $PROJECT_DIR$ but the actual path variable is not used. any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: Please, try <property name="jar.name" value=$PROJECT_DIR$/> or <property name="jar.name" value="${PROJECT_DIR}/>

Comment: thank you for this suggestion! i tried both already.. the first one simply does not work in xml (value expected error) and the second one gives me "property unknown". i also tried defining an own intellij path variable, simply for testing if the build.xml recognizes any path variables at all and it also did not change to the respective value of the new path variable. i tried it on two systems with different versions of intellij and operating systems, none of my path variables are deactivated and my settings are all pretty vanilla, so its really confusing me.